# Calculated Metrics in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

We are using Google Analytics to track the pageview and some actions. We are doing like:

```
gtag ('config', 'XXXXX', {
    'page_title' : 'the-title-we-want',
});

gtag('event', 'custom-event', 
    {
        'send_to': 'XXXXX',
        'event_category': 'event-cat-1',
        'event_label': 'event-label-1',
        'value': values
    }
);
```

On our custom dashboard, we would like to show the formula `event_label / page_title` but for only users that has `pageview title = 'the-title-we-want'` and the `event_label = 'event-label-1'`

We used Calculated Metric:

```
{{Total Events}} / {{Pageviews}}
```

But the formula above calculates all and not events with `event_label = 'event-label-1'` and `pageview title = 'the-title-we-want'`

We even put a filter like:

[image]

Is there anyway to specify the Total Events and Pageviews Title on Calculated Metric?

Answer (score 0):

**The filters should apply**:

- You can [try with a segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en) containing the same filters. The segment will tell you to which % of your total traffic it applies. If it's 100%, then it's normal you're not seeing a difference between the non-filtered and filtered versions.
- Also [watch out for sampling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en) which might kick in the moment you use filters and affect the accuracy of the reports.